# Post a form and put results in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I can't get my form to submit correctly using jquery. I have tried using the tips here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and http://api.jquery.com/submit/ but can't figure out what I am missing to have the form submit and return the results to the div instead of reloading the page. It is supposed to call an external php page to get processed and return the results.

```
<script>
    // On click "button.submit"
$("input[id^=formsubmit]").submit(function( event ) {
     // Stop form from submitting normally
    event.preventDefault();
   $.get( "functions.php?do=adminmenu", function( data ) {
    $( \".contentarea\" ).html( data );
    });
    return false;
});
</script>

<form action="#" name="submitForm">
<input type="textbox" name="test">
<input type="submit" value="Save Settings" id="formsubmit">
</form>
<div class="contentarea"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you have event.preventDeafult() there? Remove that. It prevents the form from being submitted.

Comment: @jp310 he gets after. my question is why is there `\ ` in the `$.html` call?

Comment: Did you check the chrome web developer tools? It will tell you the error. And why did you do `$(\".contentarea\") instead of $(".contentarea"). Should work fine without it

Comment: @13ruce1337 sorry, I was reusing a bit of code from my navigation menu which is concatenated with php, good catch. I thought the preventDefault had to be there to stop it from changing pages. I tried removing it and fixing the \ but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your code inside DOM ready handler `$(function() {...});` to make sure your DOM elements have been properly loaded.

Also, you can remove `return false` here as well as there's no need to escape the `$(".contentarea" )` using `\`. So try this code:

```
$(function () {
    $("input[id^=formsubmit]").submit(function (event) {
        // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get("functions.php?do=adminmenu", function (data) {
            $(".contentarea").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, I tried that but it is refreshing the page on me and not posting to the functions.php page. Also, what should I have in my form action? <form action="#" name="submitForm">

Comment: Also, I have the function tied to the submit button, is that right or should it be the form?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're not passing the data to the php file. Furthermore you have not specified the type of data handled. And if you want to use POST you should use $.post(); and not $.get();

Try it like this: I've changed the function from .get to .post, added the data you want to send to the php file and specified a data type.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#formsubmit').click(function () {
            $.post("functions.php?do=adminmenu",{test_val:$('#test_input').value},function (data) {
                $('.contentarea').html(data);
            },"json");
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="test_input" type="text" value="">
<input id="formsubmit" type="submit" value="Save Settings">
<div class="contentarea"></div>
```

Last point: What is the php file returning? Is it only a string or what? Depending on this you need to modify the function writing the returned content in the '.contentarea'.

And by the way: When submitting the information via AJAX you don't need a form around it, as it just creates the need to escape the default behaviour when submitting a form.

If it still doesn't work let me know, I'll help you.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't realize you had to pass the values, I am so used to the html form storing all those and just "knowing" everything that needs to be there. My form is built using a foreach loop with dynamic sets of names such as $row[2][0], $row[2][1] and so on, so my next project will be learning how to build an array as a subset of the loop to pass to this. Thank you again.